# Why is a query with an impossible CASE statement being evaluated?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query:

```
SELECT
CASE
  WHEN test.formula_type = 2
    THEN EXP(SUM(LN(calculated_value)))
  ELSE 1
END AS result

FROM (
  SELECT
  0 AS calculated_value,
  1 AS formula_type

  GROUP BY formula_type
) AS test

GROUP BY formula_type
```

When I run it, I get:

> psql:__scribble.sql:16: ERROR:  cannot take logarithm of zero

Which would make sense if the 4th line was executed, since `calculated_value` is being set to 0.

However, in order for line 4 to be executed `formula_type` must be 2 which is of course not true.

I assume PostgreSQL is trying to do some kind of optimisation here and calculate the value before it needs it.

But I don't understand why calculating this value, which requires the value from the sub query would be a good optimisation, since it will have to do this for every single row, even though the condition may be true only 1% of the time.

If it was a hardcoded value like SUM(LN(0)) then it would make sense to calculate the value upfront as an optimisation. But in this case it doesn't seem like it will result in any faster computations.

So, my question is, what exactly is going on here? Why is PostgreSQL trying to calculate a case that never happens?

Interestingly, if I remove the sub query's `GROUP BY` clause, the query performs as I would expect.

Note: Just to be clear, I'm not asking why I would get that error message when trying to get the Natural Logarithm of 0. I'm asking why it's even trying to get the log of 0 in the first place.

Comment: I wonder if the lack of qualification in your calculation has to do with it? Perhaps, since you qualify test.formula_type but not calculated_value, it evaluates calculated_value in a different order than it would if there were explicit qualification? DBMS optimizers do some very surprising things under the hood, and PostgreSQL doubly so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum is calculated as part of the grouping, and since the `CASE` expression contains an aggregate function, it can only be evaluated after the grouping (and summation) is done. [The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) alerts to such possibilities with the

> Note
>
> As described in [Section 4.2.14](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL), there are various situations in which subexpressions of an expression are evaluated at different times, so that the principle that “CASE evaluates only necessary subexpressions” is not ironclad. For example a constant 1/0 subexpression will usually result in a division-by-zero failure at planning time, even if it's within a CASE arm that would never be entered at run time.

The linked page is even more explicit:

> Another limitation of the same kind is that a `CASE` cannot prevent evaluation of an aggregate expression contained within it, because aggregate expressions are computed before other expressions in a `SELECT` list or `HAVING` clause are considered. For example, the following query can cause a division-by-zero error despite seemingly having protected against it:
>
> ```
> SELECT CASE WHEN min(employees) > 0
>             THEN avg(expenses / employees)
>        END
>     FROM departments;
> ```
>
> The `min()` and `avg()` aggregates are computed concurrently over all the input rows, so if any row has employees equal to zero, the division-by-zero error will occur before there is any opportunity to test the result of `min()`. Instead, use a `WHERE` or `FILTER` clause to prevent problematic input rows from reaching an aggregate function in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the interaction of aggregation with expression evaluation sometimes requires that expressions get evaluated "early".

Just use `nullif()`:

```
THEN EXP(SUM(LN(NULLIF(calculated_value, 0))))
```